# How do I enforce a function type interface on a class method in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Many methods of the `class` I'm writing implicitly have the same [function type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types). What I want to do is enforce this function type so that I can explicitly state that certain methods must conform to the function type.

e.g.

```
interface MyFunctionType {(resource: string | Resource): Something}
```

and my class has some methods that conform to this interface.

```
class MyClass {
    // ...

    someMethod() { /*...*/ }

    someMethodThatConforms(resource: string | Resource) {
        // ...
        return new Something(/*...*/);
    }

    anotherMethodThatConforms(resource: string | Resource) {
        // ...
        return new Something(/*...*/);
    }

    someOtherMethod() { /*...*/ }

    // ...
}
```

I know that `someMethodThatConforms` and `anotherMethodThatConforms` conform to the interface but now I want to know how do I *assert* that `someMethodThatConforms` and `anotherMethodThatConforms` must conform the interface `MyFunctionType` (so that if I change, `MyFunctionType` errors are thrown)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can define another interface and have `MyClass` implement it:

```
interface MyFunctionType {(resource: string | Resource): Something}

interface FixedMethods {
    someMethodThatConforms: MyFunctionType;
    // you can add more
}

class MyClass implements FixedMethods {
    someMethodThatConforms(resource: string | Resource) {
        // this method will fail type check, until we return a Something
        return 1;
    }
}
```

---

A more complex way: use `mapped type` to create a generic type:

```
interface MyFunctionType { (resource: string | Resource): Something }

// a Mapped Type to fix methods, used in place of a interface
type FixedMethods<T extends string> = {
    [k in T]: MyFunctionType
}

class MyClass implements FixedMethods<"someMethodThatConforms" | "anotherMethodThatConforms"> {
    someMethodThatConforms(resource: string | Resource) {
        // this method will fail type check, until we return a Something
        return 1;
    }

    // it also complains about lack of "anotherMethodThatConforms" method
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, that definitely does the trick but do you know if there is a way to do this without creating another interface (`FixedMethods`)?

Comment: We can also define a generic interface-like type, and use it with a list of method names, see the second part in this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the another way If you don't want to create another interface

```
interface MyFunctionType {(resource: string | Resource): Something}

class MyClass {
    // ...

    someMethod() { /*...*/}

    public someMethodThatConforms: MyFunctionType = (resource: string | Resource) => {
        // ...
        return new Something(/*...*/);
    }

    public anotherMethodThatConforms: MyFunctionType = (resource: string | Resource) => {
        // ...
        return new Something(/*...*/);
    }

    someOtherMethod() { /*...*/}

    // ...
}
```