# Can I enforce the last argument of a function in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a [function type interface](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/v2.1/pages/Interfaces.md#function-types) that I want to use to enforce a certain signature of particular functions.

Is there a way to enforce that the last argument of a function must be a particular type?

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
interface SomeType { /*...*/ }

/**
 * this is the function type I want to enforce
 * I want the last argument of any `Modifcation` to be `SomeType`
 */
interface Modification {
    (...args: [...firstArgs: any[], lastArgument: SomeType]): void
}

// enforcing `Modification`
const someModification: Modification = (firstParam: string, second: number, third: SomeType) => {
    /*...*/
}
```

I know that typescript utilizes use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#A_more_powerful_array_literal) and [tuple types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/v2.1/pages/Basic%20Types.md#tuple) but the psuedo-code above doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this?

---

**Edit:**

Disclaimer: I don't think there's a way to do what I want and this question may not be completely constructive as a result.

**Context:**

I have a set of classes and I want to enforce a certain convention on particular methods of those classes. I can enforce that a certain method must conform to a [function type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/v2.1/pages/Interfaces.md#function-types) by declaring another [interface and saying that my class implements that interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305563/how-do-i-enforce-a-function-type-interface-on-a-class-method-in-typescript).

e.g.

```
interface Convention {(arg0: string, arg1: number): Something}

interface MyClassMethodRequirements {
    myMethod: Convention,
    myOtherMethod: Convention
}

class MyClass implements MyClassMethodRequirements {
    myMethod(a: string, b: number) { return new Something(); }
    myOtherMethod(label: string, aNumber: number) { return new Something(); }
    otherMethod() { return 'just another non-conforming method' }
}
```

**What I want to achieve:**

The `Convention` above is just an example. What I want to enforce is that a method asserted to be a `Convention` must have/consider both parameters.

e.g. (pseudo-code)

```
interface NewConvention {(firstArg: any, lastArg?: RequiredType): Something}

interface MyClassMethodRequirements {
    myMethod: NewConvention,
    myOtherMethod: NewConvention
}

class MyClass implements MyClassMethodRequirements {
    myMethod(a: string, b?: RequiredType) { return new Something(); }
    // i want an error here because `myOtherMethod` doesn't list `lastArg: RequiredType` in it's parameters
    myOtherMethod(label: string) { return new Something(); }
    otherMethod() { return 'just another non-conforming method' }
}
```

for some more context, the `lastArg` of `NewConvention` is suppose to be an optional override.

Again, I don't think what I'm trying to achieve is possible so this may be unconstructive.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that currently this isn't possible (Check this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1336), but why don't you just move the last argument to be the first one and avoid this problem?

Comment: @NitzanTomer the last argument is optional by design. what a bummer :( but honest I've been very impressed with typescript so I can't complain that much

Comment: What about taking a `?`?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the maximum number of parameters, you could do as many overloads as needed.

```
type Modification =
    { (arg1: any, lastArgument: SomeType): void } |
    { (arg1: any, arg2: any, lastArgument: SomeType): void } |
    { (arg1: any, arg2: any, arg3: any, lastArgument: SomeType): void };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have the first argument (of type `SomeType`) as optional like so:

```
interface SomeType {
    a: number; // just so it's not an empty definition
}

type Modification =
    { (first: SomeType, ...rest: (string | number)[]): void; }
    | { (...rest: (string | number)[]): void; }

// fine
const someModification1: Modification = (firstParam: string, second: number) => {}
const someModification2: Modification = (third: SomeType, firstParam: string, second: number) => { }

// error
const someModification3: Modification = (firstParam: string, second: number, third: SomeType) => { }
```

Notice that if you use `any[]` for the args then that will cover the `SomeType` arg as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and if I could swap move the last argument to be first, I would but I can't because it's the last arg is optional by design which actually makes things worse. I just discovered that if you have a function type interface the last argument is optional, the method asserted to be the function type won't throw an error if it doesn't have the optional arg

Comment: e.g. `interface SomeFuncType { (a: string, b?: number): void }` and this assertion doesn't throw an error: `let func: SomeFuncType = (a) => {}`

Comment: Oh actually typescript doesn't throw any error if you the asserted function doesn't have all the arguments

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying, or why can't you have the first argument as an optional `SomeType`

Comment: I updated my question to explain what I want a bit. it's a bit out there though, be warned